# How to include specified function in the flame graph?

Tags: linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf, flamegraph

There is no function name that I want to see in the flame graph, but I'm sure this function works.
How can I do to show the function name what I want to see displayed in the flame graph?

Comment: Two things to check: 1) Are you 100% sure the function itself is called (did you check it has not been inlined during compilation for example)? 2) Have you tried searching for it when you display your flame graph in your browser (e.g. display SVG only and use `Ctrl-F` to search for your function's name)?

Comment: I have tried seraching for this function name and I am sure this function is called. In addition,some function names(not inline) will not be displayed, but  display their next level functions name in the flame graph, I don't know why

Comment: If I remember correctly flamegraphs are made from samples taken at regular intervals, and by watching what function is running for each sample. Could it be that the body of your function itself is so short that no sample was taken while it was running?